# Reset function when other element is clicked on

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a navigation that on click shows the dropdown menu and on second click it goes to that url. I can't figure out how to cancel out the function when other link in the navigation is clicked on. 
My problem is that when first link is clicked to show the dropdown and then second link will be clicked to show its dropdown, but since I have it set it up that on second it goes it the url. So, when clicked on the first link again it will go to that url instead of showing the dropdown menu. That is why I need to reset first link function when second link is clicked on and vise versa.

My fiddle example.

http://jsfiddle.net/3gpfc/37/

```
    var visibleMenu1 = $('.menuHidden0 a');
    var visibleMenu2 = $('.menuHidden1 a');

    visibleMenu1.on('click', function () {

        var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
        if (!clicks) {
            $('.drop-nav0').addClass('menuVisible');
        } else {
            $('.drop-nav0').removeClass('menuVisible');
            return true;    
        }
        $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);    
        return false;
        visibleMenu2.off('click');
    });

    visibleMenu2.on('click', function () {

        var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
        if (!clicks) {
            $('.drop-nav1').addClass('menuVisible');
        } else {
            $('.drop-nav1').removeClass('menuVisible');
            return true;
        }
        $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
        return false;
        visibleMenu1.off('click');
    });
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I still can't get what your end goal is. Can you describe step by step taking your fiddle as example, what is the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `preventDefault()` instead of `return false`.

To reverse the opposite link you need to reset its `clicks` data too.

```
var visibleMenu1 = $('.menuHidden0 a');
var visibleMenu2 = $('.menuHidden1 a');

visibleMenu1.on('click', function (e) {

    var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
    if (!clicks) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.drop-nav0').addClass('menuVisible');
    } else {
        $('.drop-nav0').removeClass('menuVisible');
    }
    $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
    visibleMenu2.data("clicks", !visibleMenu2.data("clicks"));
});

visibleMenu2.on('click', function (e) {

    var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
    if (!clicks) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.drop-nav1').addClass('menuVisible');
    } else {
        $('.drop-nav1').removeClass('menuVisible');
    }
    $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
    visibleMenu1.data("clicks", !visibleMenu1.data("clicks"));
});
```

Comment: I copied over the js to my fiddle, it seems like e.preventDefault(); did not work. I modified my original code and reset the data as you mentioned and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

try with this code

```
        var visibleMenu1 = $('.menuHidden0 a');
    var visibleMenu2 = $('.menuHidden1 a');

    visibleMenu1.on('click', function (e) {
        if(!visibleMenu2.data("clicks")){
            var clicks = $(this).data("clicks")
            if(!clicks){
                e.preventDefault();
                $(".drop-nav0").addClass("menuVisible");
                $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
            }else{
                $(".drop-nav0").removeClass("menuVisible");
                $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
            }
        }else{
             e.preventDefault();
             $(".drop-nav1").removeClass("menuVisible");
             visibleMenu2.data("clicks", false);
         }
    });

    visibleMenu2.on('click', function (e) {
         if(!visibleMenu1.data("clicks")){
            var clicks = $(this).data("clicks")
            if(!clicks){
                e.preventDefault();
                $(".drop-nav1").addClass("menuVisible");
                $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
            }else{
                $(".drop-nav1").removeClass("menuVisible");
                $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
            }
         }else{
             e.preventDefault();
             $(".drop-nav0").removeClass("menuVisible");
             visibleMenu1.data("clicks", false);
         }
    });
```